# git clone command also download when wrong github url is provided

Tags: git, github

My github repo name is dotfiles. But when I provide following command `git clone` also download the repo. Why?

```
   git clone https://github.com/al2helal/dotFiles.git
```

Comment: git ignores capitals - here's a blog on how to configure it not to https://avisi.nl/blog/2013/03/27/stop-ignoring-my-capitals-git/

Comment: please be specific in your question. Do you mean whether the URL is case sensitive or not?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund I run `git config --global core.ignorecase false` and then `git clone https://github.com/al2helal/dotFiles.git`. This works as before, but when I set `ignorecase` false it should not works.

Comment: @Ajithkumar_sekar yes.

Comment: It's Github that does the job to redirect `dotFiles.git` to `dotfiles.git`. After you create a repo named `dotfiles` under your username in Github, you can't create any other repos whose names are just different in letter cases like `DOTfiles` or `DotFiles`. So when you clone the repo with `DOTfiles` or `DotFiles`, Github knows it's in fact `dotfiles`. It has nothing to do with Git's `core.ignorecase`.

Comment: @user9719859 Github repo names are case insensitive. There is no way around it. `git config` cannot help with that as it changes local config, not how Github works.